# centering text below font awesome icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day, I'm using Font-awesome and bootstrap 4. Please check my Script first

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">

          <div class="col">
            <div class="row"> 
              <span class="fa fa-building fa-5x text-center"> </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <h3 class="text-center">Company Profile</h3>
            </div>
            </div>

          <div class="col">   
            <div class="row"> 
              <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-5x text-center"> </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <h3 class="text-center">Shopping Cart</h3>
            </div>
           </div>

         <div class="col">   
            <div class="row"> 
              <span class="fa fa-industry fa-5x text-center"> </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <h3 class="text-center">Inventory Control</h3>
            </div>
           </div>


        <div class="col">   
            <div class="row"> 
              <span class="fa fa-users fa-5x text-center"> </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <h3 class="text-center">User Management</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

with my script above i get this

[image]

as you can see, the fa icons is not at the center of text. How can i make the fa-icon in center ?

Comment: What happens instead of centering spans, you center divs?

Comment: Put icons and text in a div then centering will work.

Answer (score 4):

Add the `text-center` class to the div surrounding your icon instead of of the icon span like so:

```html
<div class="row text-center"> 
  <span class="fa fa-users fa-5x"> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your HTML markup to the below and the text under icons will be center aligned based on the class `text-center` assigned to parent `col` div.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
   <span class="fa fa-building fa-5x"> </span>
   <h3>Company Profile</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
   <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-5x"> </span>
   <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
   <span class="fa fa-industry fa-5x"> </span>
   <h3>Inventory Control</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
   <span class="fa fa-users fa-5x"> </span>
   <h3>User Management</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the "text-center" class to the "fa" element container:

from:

```
<div class="row"> 
  <span class="fa fa-building fa-5x text-center"> </span>
```

to:

```
<div class="row text-center"> 
  <span class="fa fa-building fa-5x text-center"> </span>
```

Comment: already .row and .fa classes has its default rules. So it will not work.

Comment: @ilmk my suggestion is based on tested and working solution. Not sure why you insist on adding unnecessary rules ;)

Comment: first you have to understand his question fully. Don't mislead! he is using boot 4 and based on you answer I ve created fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/90dcjgk8/. And my solution was simple to add a class. Learn well.

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can add one custom class for making those icons to center align. 

You can check this **[fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hcfjx84y/2/)**

```
.icon-center{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```